# How to make actionbar and tabs transparent

Tags: android, android-actionbar, fragment, transparent

To keep up with Google's new look I've tried to make my two top bars transparent and it hasn't worked out ie. errors/ no change occurs

here's the activity where I make the tabs (not sure if this is where I should set or not)

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    // load slide menu items
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

    // nav drawer icons from resources
    navMenuIcons = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    // adding nav drawer items to array
    // Home
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1), true, "22"));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1), true, "+10"));
    navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1)));

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#330000ff")));
    actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#550000ff")));
```

[image]

That gives me an error. I'm currently using a custom theme. What I'm I doing wrong I'm aware the code for above is meant for an activity. Is there something I'm missing in my styles or am I putting this in the wrong activity.

Comment: what is the error? please add error log.

Comment: in the line   getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
I get Cannot resolve method 'getWindow()

Answer (score 1):

if you're doing this from a fragment you will need to call:

```
getActivity().getWindow()
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but when do this the code runs but there is no change in the app

Answer (score 0):

To use this feature you must have to use **minimum API version 11**. Please check the API minimum version mentioned in Manifest file. Also check the build target set for application.

**You have written code in wrong sequence.**
**your code:**

```
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#330000ff")));
        actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#550000ff")));
        actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
```

**Problem:** you firstly set background for action bar and then accessed the activity action bar using getActionBar() method. You need to get Action Bar first then set background for it.

**Modified code:**

```
        actionBar = getActivity().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#330000ff")));
        actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#550000ff")));
```

Comment: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="11"
            android:targetSdkVersion="19"
            android:maxSdkVersion="19" /> I have this set

Comment: Is this activity or FragmentActivity?

Comment: thats the issue the code runs perfectly there's just no change in the bars transperancy. but heres the logcat http://pastebin.com/v0x5RB1W

Comment: i've changed the class i put the code in please look at the revised question

Comment: What is the use of "getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);" try to remove it and execute one more time.